# Can I use the Application module in Zend Framework 2 to provide some abstract classes or common functionality for whole system?

Tags: zend-framework2

I want to use Zend Framework 2 to build an medium size website. So, I need the one place to store some global abstract classes, controller plug-ins, view helpers. For this purpose, I decided to utilize the Application module.

Is it good or bad? If bad, where should I put all common/abstract classes to be available for whole application?

Thanks!

Comment: That is what I do. For example I have factries and view helpers I need troughout the whole application so I put them in the application folder and I think this fit's the naming convention pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is OK to do so. However a better approach would be to separate into it's own Module. Something like `Stdlib` or `Core`. This one then you could simply copy-paste into all of your other projects.